# Problema con un bucle do while a la hora de realizar un test en Java

Tags: java, backend

Estoy realizando un programa que te realiza un test y su funcionamiento es básico, mientras no puses una letra correcta, el test no avanza, el problema me viene al realizar un bucle `do... while` que pongo de condición de que no se salga de la pregunta mientras la respuesta que introduzca por teclado no sea una a, b o c, no me avanza independientemente introduzca la letra que ponga y no encuentro el fallo de lógica.

```java
do {
System.out.println("¿Fumas a menudo?" + "\n a) Si" + "\n b) Algunos días" + "\n c) No");
respuesta = sc.nextLine();
}while(!respuesta.equals("a") || !respuesta.equals("b")|| !respuesta.equals("c"));
```

Comment: Quieres repetir el ciclo mientas la respuesta No sea `a`, sea `b` o sea `c`? Es lo que estás haciendo

Comment: Exacto, y creo que la condición del while está bien, que mientras no sea a,b o c no se salga del bucle

Comment: Si escribes `a` seguro que pasa, pero el resto ya no pasan, porque son diferentes de `a`, además, la `b` y la `c` no están negadas. En cuanto encuentra que no es `a` se cumple la condición, sí o sí, y no sale del bucle `while`... Bueno, ahora sí están negadas... jjj

Comment: Jejeje, el problema es un poco de lectura. Relee mi comentario y revisa la respuesta que te están dando. Para estos casos es conveniente aprender a hacer debug de tu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo estas condicionado a que sea un valor diferente de "a" debes condicionar de la misma manera tanto "b" como "c" y no usar el operador logico or (||) si no y (&&)

Fuente:https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-6957/6n8uft4b8/index.html

```
do {
       System.out.println("¿Fumas a menudo?" + "\n a) Si" + "\n b) Algunos días" + "\n c) No");
        respuesta = sc.nextLine();
       }while(!respuesta.equals("a") && !respuesta.equals("b")&& !respuesta.equals("c"));
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias, lo probé y ya me funciona fue fallo mío de lógica, pero yo tenía entendido que la condición lógica AND se cumplía cuando todos los valores eran TRUE y por eso pensé en la OR.

Comment: la lógica es si se ingresa un valor diferente de a (y) diferente de b (y) diferente de c repite la pregunta ,en otro terminos si yo ingreso un valor diferente a esa 3 condiciones sera TRUE en las 3 ,si tu usas or y se ingresa digamos b repetira el bucle por ser distinto de a o de c,para esos  casos usamos "&&"

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora si que lo he terminado de entender bien.